# com/sun/deploy/util/WinRegistry throws ClassNotFoundException Intellij Idea

Tags: java, исключения

Всем привет! Пытаюсь прочитать значение из реестра, на стадии разработки в Intellij Idea все работает нормально:

```java
public static String getInstallLocationValue() {
    String value = WinRegistry.getString(
            WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
            "SOFTWARE\\" + ApplicationConstants.APP_NAME + "\\",
            "InstallLocation");
    System.out.println("Windows Distribution = " + value);
    return value;
}
```

Но как только все это запускаю из jar файла, получаю ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/deploy/util/WinRegistry at com.doos.utils.RegistryManager.getInstallLocationValue(RegistryManager.java:10) at com.doos.core.Main.main(Main.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.deploy.util.WinRegistry
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

Кто-то знает, как это пофиксить? Ведь библиотека то из JRE...

Comment: Нашел решение вот [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java/6163701#6163701)

Comment: Но лучше с этим справляется [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) Advapi32Util

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему с **WinRegistry** не решил, вместо него использовал класс **Advapi32Util** из [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) библиотеки

Answer (score 1):

WinRegistry - класс библиотеки sun, которая не при чем к JRE. В официальной спецификации данного класса нет. Но вы можете подключить данную библиотеку, если хотите.

[Официальный JavaDoc со списком библиотек](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

Если вы хотите все же использовать реестр Windows, рекомендую посмотреть например на этот вспомогательный класс, который под лицензией Apache: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/npanday/trunk/components/dotnet-registry/src/main/java/npanday/registry/impl/WinRegistry.java

Так же вы можете воспользоваться оффициальным инструментарием Java для хранения данных - [Prerefences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html)

Comment: По поводу подключения библиотеки... Idea при компиляции находит данный класс в папке `...JDK/jre/lib/deploy.jar`, соответственно использует его. 
Я сейчас скачал какой-то левый deploy, якобы sun-овский, и теперь jar-ник выдает мне `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.deploy.util.WinRegistry.initIDs()V` 
А вот по поводу Apache - не пойму, в какой набор библиотек входит данный класс?
А вот почему именно реестр - хочу реализовать максимальную совместимость с windows

Comment: Есть разные JDK, и не факт что она будет. Вероятней всего, что это JDK OpenJDK, а у вас по соседству еще стоит Oracle JDK где этого может и не быть. Так же, если я не ошибаюсь, данная библиотека не входит в стандартный classpath. Попробуйте вывести classpath и посмотреть на него. *Замечу, что данный класс есть и в OpenJDK, и в Oracle JDK. Но не факт что он там будет, и что он будет на других платформах*

Comment: Апачи не входит в никакой набор библиотек, данный класс вы должны сами добавить в свой проект. А та ошибка из-за того, что вы не добавили нативную библиотеку. Вам нужно deploy.dll из %JAVA_HOME%/bin, а так же msvcr100.dll и msvcr71.dll . Они **ДОЛЖНЫ** находиться в %JAVA_HOME%/bin на клиенте тоже.

Comment: Чисто класс взять не получится - за ним тянутся куча зависимостей, интерфейсов и тд... Но как я понял, это `npanday`

Comment: За ним ничего не "тянеться", кроме исключения, интерфейса который вообще не нужен, и одного простого класса OS на проверку винда ли это. И да, можете использывать NPayday если так хотите.

Comment: Ну так, получается если deploy находится в %JAVA_HOME%, то почему не используется JVM? Или я (по логике добавления) в каждый свой проект должен добавлять этот deploy?